# Вычитание count одной таблицы из count другой. Помогите составить sql-запрос, пожалуйста (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы **Таблица1** и **Таблица2**, в обоих содержатся одинаковые столбцы, скажем, **Фамилия**, **Имя**, **Отчество**.

Нужно сосчитать сколько раз встречается каждая Фамилия в каждой из таблиц, затем получить разницу между 2 таблицами и вывести 10 Фамилий, для которых разница между упоминаниями в таблицах наибольшая.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если mysql, то с подзапросами, а не PG, как написал изначально, то что-то вроде этого должно получиться.. за синтаксис не ручаюсь, общую идею хотел сказать //*с синтаксисом всё ОК*

```
SELECT ABS(t1.Количество - t2.Количество) AS 'Разница', t1.Фамилия
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Количество', Фамилия
      FROM Таблица1
      GROUP BY "Фамилия"
   ) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Количество', Фамилия
      FROM Таблица2
      GROUP BY "Фамилия"
   ) AS t2 ON (t1.Фамилия = t2.Фамилия)
ORDER BY "Разница" DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Когда это в MySQL `WITH` появилось ? И лучше abs от разницы брать она же может быть и положительная и отрицательная

Comment: Суть я понял, а раз with нет, это нужно реализовать как-то через подзапросы, но в качестве подзапросов получаются таблицы (вычитание которых невозможно), а не отдельные столбцы count